# How to put data in the fragment after the implementation into an activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have implemented two fragments into a navigation drawer (Header and footer). My problem  is: When I implement them, they are in their initial status. I have tried to put some data in these two fragments and when I launch the main activity they are unchanged. Below is some of my code

**Putting data into the bundle and transfer it to fragment**

```
infos = new Bundle();

infos.putString("Id",jObj.getString("ID"));
infos.putString("Name",jObj.getString("display_name"));

HeaderFragement hf = new HeaderFragement();

hf.setArguments(infos);
```

**The fragments implementation :**

```
 View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_header_fragement, null);
 View footer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_footer, null);

 mDrawerListView.addHeaderView(header);
 mDrawerListView.addFooterView(footer);
```

**Try to display the data transferred to the fragment:**

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    name = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.nameH);
    img = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageViewHeader);

    Bundle infos = getArguments();

    name.setText(infos.getString("Name"));
    img.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(infos.getString("ImgUrl")));


}
```

So, the problem is I want to know why even if i put data in the fragment it is not displaying .

Comment: Check the flow which statement is called first. Where you inflate Fragments and submit data or submit data and then inflate fragments.

Comment: in which method of Activity you are initializing  HeaderFragment instance and setting arguments?

Comment: Submit data first after inflate Fragments

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela HeaderFragemet is  a separate activity

Comment: Your Key's are different.

Comment: No, its correct i'm juste using some an others no :).

Comment: i see issue is in your doing getView(). As per android docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getView() - Get the root view for the fragment's layout (the one returned by onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)), if provided. But here you have two views header and footer. So i would suggest declare header and footer globally in fragment and then instead of doing getView() do header/footer.findViewById

Answer (score 0):

```
*In activity:
HeaderFragement hf = new HeaderFragement();
hf.init(infos);

and HeaderFragement 

    class HeaderFragement ...{
         Bundle infos;
         public void init(Bundle infos){
             this.infos = infos;
         }


    //update yours views in onCreateView():

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState{

       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.player_profile, container, false);
       name = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nameH);
       img = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHeader);

       name.setText(infos.getString("display_name"));
       img.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(infos.getString("file")));
       return rootView;

    }
....
}*
```

Comment: could you print "jObj.getString("ID")" values and check?

Comment: `09-23 10:32:41.055    3103-3121/com.example.user.unchained I/System.out﹕ {"code":1,"ID":"50","display_name":"karim ennassiri","file":"5379aae5ef60a.jpeg"}. I’m returning the right values
`

Comment: could you print info object init() method?

Comment: `public void init(Bundle infos){
        this.infos = infos;
    }`

Comment: public void init(Bundle infos){         this.infos = infos;  Log.d(tag, infos)    } could you check what will print?

Comment: Log need a String and not a Bundle.

Comment: i've tried this Log.i("tag", infos.getString("Id")); and its show me 50 the rigth value `09-23 11:37:48.214    1467-1467/com.example.user.unchained I/tag﹕ 50
`

Comment: could please one more time print log in onCreateview(..) { Log.i("tag", infos.getString("display_name") + " file " + infos.getString("file")); }

Comment: could you send me sample app code? will see and fix it

Answer (score 0):

```
View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_header_fragement, null);
View footer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_footer, null);

mDrawerListView.addHeaderView(header);
mDrawerListView.addFooterView(footer);
```

This code shows you inflating two views and putting it into navigation drawer, it works because fragments views are xml files like any other view and you can inflate it when ever you want. But that does not mean if you inflate this view your fragment will magically get instantiated and starts!!

if you want this to work put inflating part inside fragment code (it's probably already exists), then add a container to your drawer view and finally in your activity use fragment manager to put the fragments into container.

Comment: Well did you dynamically added fragments to your activity ever before?  It a common thing and there are plenty of code.If you are a android developer it is critical for you to learn that! here is a youtube video that shows you how to do it (also watch part 2) http://goo.gl/3FnRb2

Comment: I hope you get my point here. there are 2 ways for adding a fragment to your activity 1)by putting fragment element in your activity view (inside xml file) 2)dynamically create fragment using java then adding it to your activity with fragment manager. What you did in your code is nether of them! Your code doesn't work because there is no fragment at running time! if you put a log message inside fragment onCreateView method you see your fragment is not running! what you see on screen is only view of your fragment.

Comment: No, not before this time i'm not so advanced. Thanks anyway

Comment: My Fragments they are Header and footer for my ListView @Alireza

Comment: Ok then, you definitely need to learn that! I also recommend you to learn about layout inflation here http://goo.gl/MRctV9 Good luck